# How do you iterate over an integer variable in Jinja?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have a variable `questionCount` which is passed to the HTML page and used to create row column entries in a table. This number can vary and needs to be used in a for loop.

I need to do something like the following:

```
{% for num in 1..questionCount %}
    <td>Question {{num}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

But this does not work. What is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1..questionCount` is not valid Python (but Ruby).

Try `range(1, questionCount + 1)` instead to generate values from 1 to `questionCount`.  See also the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range) about `range`.